# mvc identity, sending email confirmation with extra parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

I am developing a mvc app using email confirmation using this line

```
 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

but I would like to send extra parameter in that method

```
 public virtual Task SendEmailAsync(TKey userId, string subject, string body);
```

is part of

```
 public class UserManager<TUser, TKey> : IDisposable
```

how can overwrite that or create an extension that accept another parameter.?

Answer (score 1):

Simply - you don't. Instead, wrap the method inside your own method which receives the extra parameter and does whatever with it.

I assume you want to use the 'extra parameter' to form your email body or subject.

```
private void MyMethod(... whatever ...)
{
  // TODO: Use whatever
  await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in MVC using some other class that inherets from `User<TUser, TKey>` like "UserManager", but it should work in any situation.

so it would be something like:

```
public static class UserManagerExtension
{
            public static Task SendEmailAsync(this UserManager manager, 
        TKey userId, string subject, string body, string extraParameter)
            {
                        //Do something with parameter
                        return manager.SendEmailAsync(userId, subject, body);
            }
}
```

So if UserManager inherets from `User<TUser, TKey>`, just replace `TKey` type with yours(`string` by default) and it should work.

Comment: Yes that is easy, thank you for the answer, but I want to get that parameter when the email. is confirmed. so I can update fields in other tables. but I just want to update that tables only if the emails is confirmed

Comment: Then you are asked wrong question. If you want to update info after conformation you need to store it somewhere: Temp Data[] or link itself. Put all your info in URL, unless it contains password, and modify Confirm Email Action to read it with token.